# How does the US deal with a polygamous immigrant family?

Tags: united-states, marriage

Will a polygamous immigrant family from a polygamous country forced into a polyamorous relationship?

Comment: [So many dups on this](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=polygamy).

Comment: @Michael Only one of the marriages would be recognized by the U.S. law, but the multiple bonding itself would not be illegal.